# How to fire akka scheduler daily for a particular time?

Tags: scheduling, quartz-scheduler, scheduler, akka, job-scheduling

I created a Akka's scheduler to send mails daily by a fixed time ( example 6:00 Am daily ).
So how to call the actor ? I mean what the logic should i use ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

Just calculate the difference between now and the following 6PM, put that as the initial delay and then repeat every 24h?

Answer (score 4):

Starting the job at 6 AM and simply repeating with 24 hour interval won't work if the server works in time zone observing [dst](/questions/tagged/dst) - for half of the year the job will fire either at 5 AM or at 7 AM, depending on when it was initially scheduled.

The OP seems to live in India (which does not observe DST), however to make the solution completely portable (and since he mentions [quartz-scheduler](/questions/tagged/quartz-scheduler)), using Quartz and CRON trigger seems safer:

```
Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
  .withIdentity("trigger3", "group1")
  .startNow()
  .withSchedule(dailyAtHourAndMinute(6, 0))
  .build();
```

Also Quartz is way more powerful. The only problem is with obtaining the target actor. Probably placing `ActorRef` in scheduler context and retrieving it in a job is the easiest way.