# How to schedule a task at specific time in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I want to execute my Scala function `cleaner.run()` at particular time every day. I was reading about Akka and Play framework. However it looks like Akka supports the intervals, e.g. "execute a task every 30 minutes", but it does not support executing tasks at the exact time. 
I would appreciate if someone can help me to put the things in order (using my particular example), because I am a bit missed with all the information and forum threads that I read.

So, this is my Scala object and I want to schedule `cleaner.run()` every day at 23:55.

```
object MyTestManager {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val cleaner = new Cleaner()

    cleaner.run()

  }
}
```

I would be interested in doing something like this, but cannot find the way of passing it to Scala 2.10.

```
import play.jobs.*;

/** Fire at 12pm (noon) every day **/ 
@On("0 0 12 * * ?")
public class Bootstrap extends Job {

    public void doJob() {
        Logger.info("Maintenance job ...");
        ...
    }

}
```

Also, after packaging the Scala code, what is the right way to launch the application so that it keeps executing every day at 23:55? Will a simple `java -jar target/scala-2.10/my-assembly-1.0.jar` do this job, or will it execute the code just once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is [Akka-Quartz](https://github.com/enragedginger/akka-quartz-scheduler).

There is a trigger functionality in there. Using that functionality you can do your task.

For more info take a look here :

1. [How to fire akka scheduler daily for a particular time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240627/how-to-fire-akka-scheduler-daily-for-a-particular-time)
2. https://blog.knoldus.com/2016/01/18/code-dissection-akka-quartz-scheduler-scalas-way-of-scheduling/